# Using vim in Linux to replace specific words

Tags: vim, grep

I have a .txt file with information as following:

```
...

353 48 338 48 338 9 353 9 **personperson走** 281 64 259 64 259 4 281 4 person

353 48 338 48 338 9 353 9 **personabc** 281 64 259 64 259 4 281 4 person

353 48 338 48 338 9 353 9 **persondef** 281 64 259 64 259 4 281 4 person

...
```

I want to replace all those bold type words to person
(The original words with normal type, not in bold)

like this:

```
...

353 48 338 48 338 9 353 9 **person** 281 64 259 64 259 4 281 4 person

353 48 338 48 338 9 353 9 **person** 281 64 259 64 259 4 281 4 person

353 48 338 48 338 9 353 9 **person** 281 64 259 64 259 4 281 4 person

...
```

I tried use the following command to replace, but the old_string part is different.

```
%s/old_string/new_string/g
```

Is there any way to use grep in (old_string) part to replace person*(stop at blank) to person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following in vim:

```
:%s/person\w\+/person/g
```

This will replace all words contining person followed by word characters by person

More informations about the substitue function in vim you can find here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
%s/\<person\zs\S\+//g
```

- This won't replace `foopersonbar` by `fooperson`
- This will replace the Chinese word `走` (OP meant "stop at blank )"